# How to append to html ?

Tags: jquery, html, mustache

I have two different html file that are being used in one js file. When i render the second html , it over rides the first one .
This is how I'm displaying it -

```
onModelLoadSuccess:function () {
                this.$el.html(Mustache.to_html(template, this.getTemplateJson()));
            },

onHistoryModelLoadSuccess:function(){
                this.$el.html(Mustache.to_html(HistoryTemplate,   this.getHistoryTemplateJson()));
            },
```

The second method being called after first one. How do I append two instead of one over writing the other one ?

Answer (score -1):

Use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/). It shall insert HTML you pass at the end.

Comment: I get this error : Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent

Comment: @dharag Well, do not add an element to itself. Hard to say what is wrong without the code. jsfiddle?